# Why validation message is not displayed for a selectOneMenu component(JSF 2)?

Tags: java, validation, jsf, jsf-2, java-ee-6

I use this class for doing validation from input fields:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class UserInputValidation {

    public void validateCity(FacesContext context, UIComponent validate,
            Object value) {
        String inputFromField = (String) value;     

        if (inputFromField.equals("") || inputFromField.equals(" ")) {
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Odaberite grad");
            throw new ValidatorException(msg);
        }
    }
//...
}
```

And this is the managed bean that holds the inputed values:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class InputController {

    //Attributes
    private String city;
   //Get set methods
```

Why when i create a selectOneComponent and i select the first component(blank input), the validation message is not shown?

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="city" value="#{inputController .city}">                
                <f:selectItems value="#{searchController.formatedCities()}" validator="#{userInputValidation.validateCity}"/>
            </h:selectOneMenu>
            <span style="color: red;"><b><h:message for="city"
                    showDetail="true" /></b></span>
```

The first of the fields in the selectOneMenu is a blank(The formatedCitiesMethod() returns a "" as first element), so why the validation message is not being shown if the form is submit button is clicked with the blank selected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `validator` attribute has to go in the `<h:selectOneMenu>`, not in the `<f:selectItems>`

Said that, why don't you just use `required="true"`? Why is the validator a `@ManagedBean` instead of a `@FacesValidator`?

Comment: I was thinking about `required="true"`, but i thought that if the blank was selected, that would also count as a valid selection, so validation would pass as correct.

Comment: No, empty string and `null` will trigger `required="true"`. Only a space not. Just set the default value to `null` and use if necessary a converter to trim spaces from all input strings before validation.

Comment: Cool i didn't know that so in this case i don't even need the validation method :) Thanks!

Comment: If he had used `@FacesValidator` he had to use `<f:validator validatorId="userInputValidation " />` and implement Validator interface. The `validator` attribute lets you specify a Custom Validation Method from a ManagedBean, though he didn't needed another MBean, he could have used `InputController`.

Comment: @Cosmin: the class is clearly dedicated as a validator (classname ends with `Validator`), so I was just wondering.